# symfony2 KnpPaginatorBundle automatically generate query string

Tags: php, symfony, twig

is there any method in twig to make KnpPaginatorBundle generate its query string automatically? I want something like this:

`?sort=id&page=2` to be automatically inserted when i call function like this: `knp_current_parameters()`

so, is there such functionality?

Or How do I generate a link that will contain sort and page params, without manually passing them within controller?